# If element ID found in iframe within parent page do something

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have one single iframe within parent page on the same domain. I need when ID 'applications' is found in iframe to trigger changes in parent page.
 Is this javascript function correct ?

```
function load(){
if (window.frames[0].document.getElementById('applications'))
{
var str=document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML;
var n=str.replace("Login","Delogare");
document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML=n;
document.getElementById('tst').title ='logout';
document.getElementById('tst').href='logout';
document.getElementById('prt').href='../profil/cont.html?refresh';
}}
```

Comment: who can say? it's quite specific

Comment: Function looks good. Do register load function with iframe onload